# Retrieving mapserver source mxd?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, map-service

I am using a Arcgis 10.3 server

I have been looking for a way to find the source mxd from feature services that have been published. I have a server that has many services on it. I know the source for those services are mxds. So what i am looking for is a way in python to be able to get the source of the mxd, from there I will be able to list the layers and everything, I already have script that can do that. For now i just need to be able to find the source mxd for each service, I will probably make an csv out of or something as the output.

http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/example-write-properties-of-all-services-to-a-csv-file.htm

Currently I have used the above script to find all the services, but this does not list the source mxd or the layers in each service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no way to currently do this, Ended up changing the naming convection of my folders and the source mxd, so the mxd relates to the service name, made a script runs a loop that looks through the folders and then outputs an csv using the name as the service name as well as the datasources.